# A twisted version of the modular curve $X_1(N)$

Tags: modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

The modular curve $Y_1(N)$ is known to parametrize pairs $(E,P)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve and $P$ is a point in $E$ of exact order $N$ (at least if $N$ is invertible in the base; if not, one can use an approach suggested by Drinfeld, as seen Chapter 1 in the famous book by Katz and Mazur). It has a natural compatification $X_1(N)$.

I am interested in a "twisted version" of $Y_1(N)$, parametrizing pairs $(E,f)$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve and $f:\mu_N\to E$ is a monomorphism of groups schemes, with a map of such pairs $(E,f)$ must restrict to the identity on $\mu_N$ (if $N$ is invertible in the base). If the base contains the $N$-roots of unity, then we have an isomorphim between such curves (fixing an isomorphism between $\mu_N$ and $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$).

> Do you know a place where this curve has been studied? For example, it is known it's rational points over $\mathbb{Q}$?

> What could be the definition of such curve if $N$ is not invertible in the base (using Drinfeld approach, for example, as in Katz-Mazur)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, this is one of my favourites in the "subtle issues that people often overlook" categories :-)

The point is that this modular curve, let's call it $Y_\mu(N)$ (classifying pairs $(E, \mu_N \hookrightarrow E)$) is *canonically isomorphic* to $Y_1(N)$ (classifying embeddings of the constant group scheme): given $\alpha: \mu_N \hookrightarrow E$ you can consider the Cartier dual of $\alpha$ as a map $\alpha^\vee: (\mathbf{Z}/N) \hookrightarrow E'$, where $E' = E / \operatorname{image}(\mu)$. So $(E', \alpha^\vee)$ is a point of $Y_1(N)$. Similarly, there's a map going the other way. So there are canonical maps
$$Y_1(N) \to Y_\mu(N)$$
and
$$Y_\mu(N) \to Y_1(N)$$
whose composite is the identity; and this works over pretty much any base ring where you can make sense of the objects involved.

However, the above maps *don't commute* with the standard complex uniformisations of both $Y_1(N)$ and $Y_\mu(N)$ by the upper half-plane $\mathcal{H}$ modulo $\Gamma_1(N)$. (Actually, the map between them is precisely the Atkin--Lehner involution on the complex points, $z \mapsto -1/Nz$.) So these curves are "the same" as abstract curves; e.g. if $Y_1(N)$ has $\mathbf{Q}$-points, then so does $Y_\mu(N)$, but they aren't given by the images of the same points of $\mathcal{H}$.

On the other hand, if you work over a $\mathbf{Z}[1/N, \zeta_N]$-algebra (such as $\mathbf{C}$), you can identify $\mu_N$ with $(\mathbf{Z}/N)$ as group schemes; this gives you a second isomorphism between the two curves, which *does* commute with the complex uniformisation -- but is not defined over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$.

So these two objects are "nearly the same" in two different but incompatible ways: you can have an isomorphism between them that respects the Galois action, or one that respects the complex uniformisation, but not both. This causes no end of headaches (because a lot of authors are so sure they know which is the 'right' model of $Y_1(N)$ that they don't even bother to specify which one they're using).